# looker studio summing formula

Tags: formula, looker-studio

I am trying to create a formula to sum up ad information based on an ad content type.

The content type is identified in the ad name with text, such as "Lifestyle" or "Product"

The issue I am having is that sometimes an ad can have multiple content types and specific keywords in the name, for example, "Lifestyle UGC" or "Product USP".

The formula is only summing the data to the first text contains query.

I would like for it to sum for each content type individually. So the data could be summed up in multiple rows if the ad is a lifestyle and a UGC.

I tried this forumula: CASE
WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(Ad Name,'Lifestyle') THEN 'Lifestyle'
WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(Ad Name,'Product') THEN 'Product'
WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(Ad Name,'USP') THEN 'USP'
WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(Ad Name,'UGC') THEN 'UGC'
WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(Ad Name,'Press') THEN 'Press'
WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(Ad Name,'Testimonial') THEN 'Testimonial'
WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(Ad Name,'Graphic') THEN 'Graphic'
Else 'Other'
END

I experienced that it will sum up the ads data in the first text contains group that appears in the name.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by making several custom fields like USP with this formula.

```
IF (CONTAINS_TEXT(Ad Name, 'USP', 1, 0))
```

And then you can add metric with SUM aggregation.
You can do the same things with Product, Lifestyle and whatnot.

Comment: Hello Anthony, that is not exactly what I am going for. 

Doing it that way makes a column for each category. It then says The category or Null. I would have 7 rows with just the name or null in them. 

I am looking to segment the ad names data by text contains. So if the ad name has both Lifestyle and USP it would be adding the data to both categories. 

I tried using ChatGPT but the closest thing I got was repeating this for each category: 

`CASE
  WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(Ad Name, 'Lifestyle') THEN 'Lifestyle'
  ELSE NULL
END +`

However, Lookerstudio does not accept the +'s